# MacBookPro 8,2 i7-2820QM real-time "turbo frequency"

Tags: macbook-pro, intel-core-i7, turbo-boost

I am on a MacBook Pro with this processor: http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=52227, computing a strictly single-threaded workload. Since the CPU has a clock speed of 2.3 GHz and a max Turbo Frequency of 3.4 GHz, I'd like to check whether the 3.4GHz is ever reached in practice. Can you please recommend a Mac OS X tool (possibly with a GUI) that shows that?

Answer (score 1):

I know this was posted a long time ago, but I'm surprised no one answered.  I use these for my menubar and my dashboard, from [iSLayer](http://www.islayer.com/apps/).

Comment: The free Dashboard widgets do not show actual CPU frequency?